# Adding facebook custom tabs using URL method, no longer working

Tags: facebook, tabs

we can still add some of our custom apps to customers pages.

every now and then we get a content error when using the URL method as below

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=xxxx&next=ScriptURLxxxx/exec?tabpage=TABNAME

This works 99% of the time, although a new onboarding we receive the error "Content is not available right now", I then tried this same method on another page and worked fine.

Below is a method I found on Facebook Dev page. Although for the life of me cannot get it to authenticate when running the Curl commands with correct variables.

Has anyone had this whilst adding Facebook Custom App Tabs

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that's not due to the limitation mentioned in the docs - that only pages with >2k likes can still add page tabs?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.